# Is there a word for someone who speaks before they think

Tags: synonyms, antonyms, writing

Well as the title says, is there a word for a person who talks *before* they think? And if it is, whats the word and what's the **antonym**? I need to know this for to characters in a novel. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **[loose-tongued](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/loose-tongued)** adj
>
> careless or irresponsible in talking.

It seems 'tight-lipped' can be used as an antonym of 'loose-tongued'.

> [**tight-lipped**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tight-lipped) adj
>
> Reluctant to speak; close-mouthed.